# Darle mas tiempo a show en ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, div

tengo este codigo y quiero darle un poco mas de tiempo al momento de mostrar el elemento #result.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.para_envio').submit(function(){
  
 var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to update?");
      if (x){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ercc.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
                //$('#result').show(3000);
    
    $('#result') .html(data) ;
    $('#result').hide(5000);

            }
        });//end ajax
  return false;
      }
      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con setTimeOut, donde el primer parámetro es una función y el segundo es el tiempo (en milisegundos. 1000ms = 1seg) que tarda en ejecutarse:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('#result').show(3000);
 }, 3000);

 success: function(data) {
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('#result').show(3000);
   }, 3000);                

   $('#result') .html(data) ;
   $('#result').hide(5000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta con encadenar un [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) con el tiempo que desees a la cadena de eventos para que realice lo que deseas:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').hide();
  $('.para_envio').submit(function() {
    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to update?");
    if (x) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "//httpbin.org/post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          /* Encadenamos aparición, espera y desaparición de los datos */
          $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data)).
            fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        }
      });  //end ajax
      return false;
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form class="para_envio" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="hidden" name="valor" value="prueba"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

En este caso primero aparece (suavemente) con un `fadeIn`, luego se mantiene durante 5000 ms (5 segundos) y por último desaparece suavemente con `fadeOut`.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte me ha ayudado mucho

Comment: gracias por tu aporte me ha ayudado mucho

Comment: De nada, un placer. Si te ha ayudado y es lo que necesitabas marca la respuesta como correcta para dar por solucionada la pregunta. Gracias :)